# DataChangeEventArgs as a parameter

Tags: c#, .net

how to pass the DataChangeEventArgs value to the another function
code

```
private void DataChangeHandler(object sender, DataChangeEventArgs e)
   {
       // The invoke handling is only required when the callback handler writes data into Windows dialogs
       if (InvokeRequired)
       {
           BeginInvoke(new DataChangeEventHandler(DataChangeHandler), new object[] { sender, e });

           return;
       }

       Thread th1 = new Thread(param.update);
       th1.Start(e);

   }

public void update(DataChangeEventArgs e)
{
}
```

it will be display the error like

1. the best overloaded method match for
   'System.Threading.Thread.Thread(System.Threading.ThreadStart)'
   has some invalid arguments
2. Argument '1': cannot convert from
   'method group' to
   'System.Threading.ThreadStart'
   please provide the proper solution

Answer (score 1):

You could use ParameterizedThreadStart and change your worker method:

```
private void DataChangeHandler(object sender, DataChangeEventArgs e)
{
    // The invoke handling is only required when the callback handler writes data into Windows dialogs
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        BeginInvoke(new DataChangeEventHandler(DataChangeHandler), new object[] { sender, e });
        return;
    }

   Thread th1 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(param.update));
   th1.Start(e);
}

public void update(object e)
{
  DataChangeEventArgs x = (DataChangeEventArgs)e;

  //other code
}
```

Comment: @sangita If you used this solution, you should mark the answer as "accepted" so that others can see that there is an accepted solution to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void DataChangeHandler(object sender, DataChangeEventArgs e)
   {
       // The invoke handling is only required when the callback handler writes data into Windows dialogs
       if (InvokeRequired)
       {
           BeginInvoke(new DataChangeEventHandler(DataChangeHandler), new object[] { sender, e });

           return;
       }
       DataChangeEventArgs args = (DataChangeEventArgs)e;
       Thread th1 = new Thread(update(args.Value));
       th1.Start(e);

   }

public void update(DataChangeEventArgs e)
{
}
```